# Magento full product path not working

Tags: product, category, url-rewrite

I have imported product from another shop using Magmi. And enabled Use category paths in product urls.

1. `Truncated core_url_rewrite table` .
2. `reindexed everything`.

   3.`cleared cache`

   But still full product path doesn't work.

`$item->getProductUrl()` returns path like `http://website.com/catalog/product/view/id`...

I need urls to look like http://website.com/category/subcategory/product.html

I'v tried to use some function to return product url with full path but still i can't enter that product it goes to 404 page.

What should i do? I really need help on this one.

Comment: Can you give examples of the newly created URL keys in `core_url_rewrite` please?

Comment: @NiGe -

id_path - request_path - target_path


product/581 alamutas.html catalog/product/view/id/581
product/582 laimes-atradimas-finding-laime.html catalog/product/view/id/582